# Why does type inference fails in this case?

Tags: scala, type-inference

The following code works well:

```
object InfDemo {    
  class Tag[T]
  case object IntegerTag extends Tag[Int]
  case object StringTag extends Tag[String]
  val TagOfInteger: Tag[Int] = IntegerTag

  def defaultValue[T](typ: Tag[T]): T = typ match {
    case IntegerTag => 0
    case StringTag => ""
    // case TagOfInteger => 0 // this not works
  }     
}
```

but the following code will report type inference error:

```
object InfDemo2 {
    val ClassOfInteger: Class[Integer] = classOf[Integer]
    val ClassOfString : Class[String] = classOf[String]
    def defaultValue[T](typ: Class[T]): T = typ match {
      case ClassOfInteger => 0
      case ClassOfString => ""
   }
}
```

So what is the difference between these code, and how scala does the type inference here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with using `Class` over `Tag`, and all to do with matching against a case object (such as `IntegerTag` and `StringTag`) over matching against a mere value (such as `TagOfInteger`, `ClassOfInteger` and `ClassOfString`).

Let's try to compile 4 variants of your first example:

Version 1:

```
class Tag[T]
case object IntegerTag extends Tag[Int]
case object StringTag extends Tag[String]
def defaultValue[T](typ: Tag[T]): T = typ match {
  case IntegerTag => 0
  case StringTag => ""
}
```

Version 2:

```
class Tag[T]
case class IntegerTag() extends Tag[Int]
case class StringTag() extends Tag[String]
def defaultValue[T](typ: Tag[T]): T = typ match {
  case IntegerTag() => 0
  case StringTag() => ""
}
```

Version 3:

```
class Tag[T]
class IntegerTag extends Tag[Int]
class StringTag extends Tag[String]

def defaultValue[T](typ: Tag[T]): T = typ match {
  case _: IntegerTag => 0
  case _: StringTag => ""
}
```

Version 4:

```
class Tag[T]
val IntegerTag: Tag[Int] = new Tag[Int]
val StringTag: Tag[String] = new Tag[String]
def defaultValue[T](typ: Tag[T]): T = typ match {
  case IntegerTag => 0 // error: type mismatch
  case StringTag => "" // error: type mismatch
}
```

If you try to compile them you'll see that version 1, 2 and 3 compile fine, while version 4 does not.
The reason is that in version 1, 2  and 3, the pattern matching allows the compiler to know for sure which type is `T`:

- In version 1 we do `case IntegerTag =>`. Because `IntegerTag`  is a case object, we know for sure that there cannot be any instance that is equal to `IntegerTag` (except for `IntegerTag` itself). So if there is a match here, the runtime type of `IntegerTag` can only be `IntegerTag`, which extends `Tag[Int]`. Thus we can safely infer that `T = Int`.
- In  version 2 we do `case IntegerTag() =>`. Here `IntegerTag` is a case class, and as such we know that there can only bea match here if `typ` is an instance of `IntegerTag`, which extends `Tag[Int]`. Thus we can safely infer that `T = Int`.
- In version 3 we do `case _: IntegerTag =>`. In other words, we explictly match against the `IntegerTag` type. So once again we know that `typ` is of type `IntegerTag`, which extends `Tag[Int]`, and we can safely infer that `T = Int`.

Now, the problem with version 4 is that we have no guarantee about the runtime type of `typ`. This is because in this version we just do `case IntegerTag =>`, where `IntegerTag` is a `val`. In other words, there will be a match if and only if `typ == IntegerTag`. The problem is that the fact that `typ` is equal to `IntegerTag` (or in other words that `typ.==(IntegerTag)` returns true) tells us nothing about the runtime type of `typ`.
Indeed, one can very well redefine equality in such a way that it can be equal to instance of unrelated classes (or simply be equal to instances of the same generic class but with different type arguments). By example, consider:

```
val StringTag: Tag[String] = new Tag[String]
val IntegerTag: Tag[Int] = new Tag[Int] { 
  override def equals( obj: Any ) = {
    (obj.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] eq this) || (obj.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] eq StringTag)
  }
}
println(StringTag == StringTag) // prints true
println(StringTag == IntegerTag) // prints false
println(IntegerTag == IntegerTag) // prints true
println(IntegerTag == StringTag) // prints true
```

`IntegerTag == StringTag` returns true, which means that if we passed `StringTag` to method `defaultValue`, there would be a match with `case IntegerTag =>`, even though `StringTag`actuall is an instance of `Tag[String]` rather than of `Tag[Int]`. This shows that indeed the fact the there is a match for `case IntegerTag =>` tells us nothing regarding the runtime  type of `typ`. And so the compiler cannot assume anything about the exact type of `typ`: we only know from its declared static type that it is a `Tag[T]` but `T` is still unknown.